# Is it possible to assign a task to a specific worker in Ray?

Tags: ray

Specifically I'd like my parameter store worker to always be invoked on the HEAD node, and not on any of the workers. This way I can optimize the resource configuration. Currently the parameter store task seems to get started on a random server, even if it called first, and even if it is followed by a ray.get()

Maybe it's possible to do something like:
`ps = ParameterStore.remote(onHead=True)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start the "head" node with an extra custom resource and then you can make the parameter store actor require that custom resource. For example, start the head node with:

```
ray start --head --resources='{"PSResource": 1}'
```

Then you can declare the parameter store actor class with

```
@ray.remote(resources={"PSResource": 1})
class ParameterStore(object):
    pass


ps = ParameterStore.remote()
```

You can also declare the parameter store actor regularly and change the way you invoke it. E.g.,

```
@ray.remote
class ParameterStore(object):
    pass


ps = ParameterStore._remote(args=[], resources={"PSResource": 1})
```

You can read more about resources in Ray at https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html.